# Best way to edit font in Igx Grid column cells

Tags: css, angular, ignite-ui, ignite-ui-angular

Can't find a good method for changing the font for all grids across the application. I know of `[cellClasses]` and `[cellStyles]` but it seems unnecessary to set these for every column on every page of the application. Is there a way to this in global styles? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Indeed applying styles of every column (and cell) across multiple components is a bit excessive for what you are trying to do. Those are more geared towards custom conditional styling.

The grid and cells will normally inherit fonts, so it's super simple to change - you can add a rule scoped to the entire `igx-grid` or specifically the `igx-grid-cell` like so:

```
igx-grid-cell {
  font-family: monospace
}
```

Per [Abdul's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62273823/1613589) the main `styles.scss` is the likely candidate for the typography to apply app-wide (avoiding potential view encapsulation issues). Here's a quick example with the above applied:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/grid-cell-font?file=src/styles.scss

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I haven't work with Angular for a while however I remember you can have your global style settings in `src/styles.css` or `src/styles.scss`or `src/styles.sass`. Add your grids styles to this file and you should be good to go.

Here is a link to [angular global-styles](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles) and [angular File structure](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

It's best if you use the typography mixins in your `scss` theming setup. This way you would modify the fonts for all components and not just individual grid cells. Take a look at this article, it explains how to modify everything related to typography:

https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/themes/typography.html

Example with the font-family:

```
$my-type-scale: igx-type-scale();

@include igx-typography(
    $font-family: "'Roboto', sans-serif",
    $type-scale: $my-type-scale,
    $base-color: #484848
);
```